# TFS 2013: Burndown chart is inaccurate

Tags: tfs

I'm facing a problem with our burndown chart on `TFS 2013`.
As you can see in the image, the chart for our current sprintdisplays around 350h remaining work, while there is only 251h of work left as you can see on the right side of the image.

No work was performed in the sprint since 24.12.2015, since everybody was (and still is) on vacation :-)

[image: image of the burndown chart]

Any ideas why the burndown chart is looking like this? Any solutions?

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query for the burndown and the capacity pane are slight different. The capacity pane uses a tree query, while the burndown uses a flat query.

The effect is that when you have nested tasks, the intermediate tasks won't be shown in the iteration backlog / capacity pane, but if these intermediate tasks have hours they are included in the burndown.

You can easily check whether this is the case by clicking on the "Create Query" button in the toolbar of the iteration backlog and see if you have nested tasks.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. We had some tasks with remaining work scheduled for sprint 1, that were not linked to any PBIs in Sprint 1 anymore. Someone screwed up here :) I had never found that if I wouldn't have followed your hint, so thanks!

Comment: Please note that in TFS 2015 RTM and up, the task board will show these unparented tasks as well!